# Updating multiple rows with unique columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns, id (Primary Key) and two unique Key column, column_1_id and column_2_id.

A column_1_id (referenced of a user's ID) can exist many times in the DB, but must have a different column_2_id each time.

The below diagram is valid.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| ID | column_1_ID | column_2_ID |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          2  |
|  2 |           1 |          4  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

The below diagram is NOT valid.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| ID | column_1_ID | column_2_ID |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          2  |
|  2 |           1 |          2  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to update rows with column_2_ID with either 2 or 4. If a user (referenced by column_1_ID) has a row with column_2_ID = 2, and a row with column_2_ID = 4. The row with column_2_ID = 4 should be deleted, and the row with column_2_ID = 2 updated to be column_2_ID = 3.

However, if a user has a row with column_ID_2 = 2, row with column_ID_2 = 4 and a row with column_ID_2 = 3. The row that have column_ID_2 = 2 and the row with column_ID_2 = 4 should be deleted.

The end goal is to have no rows exist that have a column_2_ID equal to either 2 or 4.

So for example currently the below diagrams can, and do exist.

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| ID | column_1_ID | column_2_ID |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          2  |
|  2 |           1 |          3  |
|  3 |           1 |          4  |
+----+-------------+-------------+

+----+-------------+-------------+
| ID | column_1_ID | column_2_ID |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          2  |
|  2 |           1 |          4  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

Both the above examples should result in the below:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| ID | column_1_ID | column_2_ID |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |          3  |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

A new table cannot be created, the ID Primary Key MUST be maintained.

Below is a sample of what I've tried, among other things:

```
UPDATE table
SET column_2_id=3
WHERE column_2_id IN (2,4)
```

However it returns:

> Duplicate entry '2-3' for key 'integrity_idx'.

I've tried various solutions, but none are coming up with what I need. The Primary Key (id) must be maintained - creating a new table isn't possible.

Comment: Imagine a col1ID  of 1 has both a 2, and 4 in col2ID.  1-2 becomes 1-3 and 1-4 tries to become 1-3 but fails due to dup key...  or maybe a 1-3 already exists and now you try to change 1-2 to 1-3... how do you want to handle that.  too many unknowns.

Comment: Valid point - I will have to find out tomorrow.

Comment: This makes sense to me -- can we re-open this question?
  
For clarity, I refer to column_1_ID as user and column_2_ID as job.
  
If a user has any job IN (2,3,4), then that user should only have a job of 3.
The ID of the original row must also stay the same, if there were any.

You can accomplish this with a series of queries, but they are too long to post in this box. [I have included them in this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/NEMKUx5s)

Comment: @xQbert Can we re-open this please?

Comment: Update the original question with more details. Reopen process is started

Comment: I can only see this as a 2 step process: Delete all the records that are 2,3,4 in col_2_ID except the one with the lowest ID then update the column_2_ID to 3 for that record `DELETE 
FROM table 
WHERE column_2_ID in (2,3,4) 
and ID NOT in (SELECT Min(ID) 
                 FROM table 
                 WHERE column_2_ID in (2,3,4)
                 GROUP BY column_1_ID);

UPDATE table
SET column_2_ID = 3
WHERE ColumN_2_ID in (2,3,4);`

Comment: IMO all ambiguity has been cleared up and the question could be re-opened.  And @BillyPurvis Awesome job on improving the question.  The examples ,expected results and requirement descriptions cleared up all ambiguity imo.  Sometimes the reopen process doesn't work (not enough attention to re-open) in which case it may be necessary to copy this to a new question and withdraw this one.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks! Do we know how long it should take to re-open? If not, I'll re-post. 

Thanks again - apologies for the bad question first time!

Comment: It's a voting process 5 reopen votes required by moderators and those with enough contributions.  you have 2 at the moment.

Comment: Can you explain the tables below `So for example currently the below diagrams can, and do exist.`? It looks like you had two tables with the same schema. If it's one table - please put rows together without repeating the column names, because it's confusing.

Comment: It's one table - the diagrams describe the possible occurrences that could happen within the DB.